# python: range not being executed

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

App executes but the range doesn't. In my CSV file, it only shows the first entry. I've also come across index out of range errors when scraping other fields. Any help would be appreciated. I'm learning.

```
import requests  
import csv  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


f = csv.writer(open('salons.csv', 'w'))  
f.writerow(['Name'])

pages = []


    for i in range(0, 10600):  
url = 'http://www.aveda.com/locator/get_the_facts.tmpl?SalonID=' + str(i) +' '  
    pages.append(url)

for item in pages:  
    page = requests.get(item)  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')  

salon_name_list = soup.find(class_='getthefacts__store_meta_info--store_phone')  
    salon_name_list_items = salon_name_list.find_all('li', class_='phone')  

for salon_name in salon_name_list_items:  
    names = salon_name.contents[0]

f.writerow([names])
```

Comment: Your indentation on and below the lines `for i in range(0, 10600):` is incorrect. Even if the `for` was properly aligned, since url isn't indented, it is not inside the for loop, so the for loop will run by itself and then u`url = ` will be called afterwards

Comment: thanks, matthew. i have it properly formatted but didn't know how to paste the code in here correctly. do you see any other errors that might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you tried to find phone numbers is not how you should do. Phone numbers are within `a` tag under class name `phone`. Try this instead. It will fetch you the phone numbers you are interested in:

```
import requests ; import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('salons.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(['Name'])

for i in range(0, 10600):  
    url = 'http://www.aveda.com/locator/get_the_facts.tmpl?SalonID={0}'.format(i)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    for salon_name in soup.select('.phone a'):
        names = salon_name.text
        print(names)
        writer.writerow([names])
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have indented your code. Format it properly in the question. And you may not need two for loops.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = csv.writer(open('salons.csv', 'w'))
f.writerow(['Name'])

for i in range(0, 10600):  
    url = 'http://www.aveda.com/locator/get_the_facts.tmpl?SalonID=' + str(i) +'/'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    salon_name_list = soup.find(class_='getthefacts__store_meta_info--store_phone')
    salon_name_list_items = salon_name_list.find_all('li', class_='phone')
    for salon_name in salon_name_list_items:
        names = salon_name.contents[0]
        f.writerow([names])
```